Using titlesec to change chapter formatting
I have the following main.tex document:
\documentclass{something}

\definecolor{acol}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{bcol}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{ccol}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{dcol}{HTML}{000000}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{100pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \vspace*{-3em} 
        \fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\bfseries 
        \textcolor{acol}{
            %\rule[0.25em]{2in}{0.75pt} 
            My Title
        }
    \end{flushleft}
\end{adjustwidth}
\begin{flushleft} 
      \LARGE
      \textit{\textcolor{bcol}{My Subtitle}}
\end{flushleft}
\vspace{-1in}
\begin{flushright} 
    \Large \text{\textcolor{ccol}{My Name}}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{-0.225in}
\begin{flushright}
\large \textcolor{dcol}{\today}
\end{flushright} \vspace{0.45in}


\end{document}

And the following style file, something.cls:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{something}
\LoadClass[10pt, oneside]{book}

\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage[letterpaper, margin=1in, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[p, osf]{cochineal}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{bookmark}
\RequirePackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, amsfonts}

When run, this produces:

This is what I want. However, I would like to be able to include multiple of these "headings" and have them all appear in the table of contents. For this reason, I am trying to use the titlesec package to redefine \chapter, which I am not using otherwise, to the formatting of "My Title" in the image above. I thought something like this might work:
\documentclass{something}

\definecolor{acol}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{bcol}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{ccol}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{dcol}{HTML}{000000}

\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\bfseries}{}{0.5em}{} 
%%% also want to add color, spacing needs to be changed

\newpage
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{100pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \vspace*{-3em}
        \chapter{My Title}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{adjustwidth}
\begin{flushleft} 
      \LARGE
      \textit{\textcolor{bcol}{My Subtitle}}
\end{flushleft}
\vspace{-1in}
\begin{flushright} 
    \Large \text{\textcolor{ccol}{My Name}}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{-0.225in}
\begin{flushright}
\large \textcolor{dcol}{\today}
\end{flushright} \vspace{0.45in}


\end{document}

However, I get:


Possible solution:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[p,osf]{cochineal}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% initialize
\protected\def\hellostudysubtitle{}
\protected\def\hellostudyname{}
\protected\def\hellostudydate{}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\hellostudychapter{\hellostudysubtitle}{\hellostudyname}{\hellostudydate}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
  {\huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\newcommand{\hellostudychapter}[4]{%
  \makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
    \hspace{-50pt}%
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      \fontsize{36}{36}\bfseries\color{acol}#4 \\[1ex]
      \LARGE\itshape\color{bcol}#1
      \end{tabular}%
    }%
    \hfill
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
      \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
      \LARGE\color{ccol}#2 \\[0.5ex]
      \large\color{dcol}#3
      \end{tabular}%
    }%
    \hspace{-50pt}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\hschapter}[4]{%
  \def\hellostudysubtitle{#2}%
  \def\hellostudyname{#3}%
  \def\hellostudydate{#4}%
  \chapter{#1}%
}

\definecolor{acol}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{bcol}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{ccol}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{dcol}{HTML}{000000}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\hschapter{My Title}{My Subtitle}{My Name}{\today}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}


